# Editing data in QTableModel not changed after editing

Tags: qt, qt4, qtableview

I have inherited QAbstractTableModel as described [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modelview.html#2-5-the-minimal-editing-example). I have coded setData as:

```
bool TableModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if(role == Qt::EditRole)
    {
        Data[index.row()][index.column()]= value.toString();
        qDebug()<<Data[index.row()][index.column()];//to check entered data passed or not
    }
    return true;
}

Qt::ItemFlags TableModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    return Qt::ItemIsEditable|Qt::ItemIsEnabled|Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
}
```

and in mainwindow I have connected model and view as:

```
connect(model,SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),ui->tableView,SLOT(dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)));
```

but after editing data is not updated in view. I tried with emitting dataChanged signal from setData function but it is not working. What I missed in my code?

---

data function:

```
QVariant TableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{

    switch(role)
    {
    case Qt::DisplayRole:
        if(index.column()==0)
        {
        return index.row()+1;
        }
        break;
    case Qt::DecorationRole:

        if(index.column()==1)
        {
            QColor c;
            c.setRgb(0,200,200,200);
            return c;
        }
        break;

    case Qt::ToolTipRole:
        if(index.column()==2)
        {
        return "colum 3";
        }
        break;
    case Qt::StatusTipRole:
        return "Not editable";
        break;

    case Qt::FontRole:
    {
        QFont f;
        f.setFamily("Times");
        f.setBold(true);
        f.setKerning(true);
        return f;
    }
        break;
    case Qt::TextAlignmentRole:
    {
        return Qt::AlignCenter;
    }
        break;

    case Qt::BackgroundRole:
        if(index.column()==2)
        {
            QColor b;
            b.setRgb(100,100,250,200);
        return b;
        }
        break;

    case Qt::ForegroundRole:
    {
        QColor b;
        b.setRgb(0,100,250,200);
        return b;
    }

    case Qt::CheckStateRole:
        if(index.column()==3)
        {
            if(index.row()==1) return true;
            return false;
        }
        break;

    case Qt::InitialSortOrderRole:
        return Qt::AscendingOrder;// use not clear
    }

    return QVariant();
}
```

Comment: You need to emit the `dataChanged()` signal if the data was successfully set, but in your code you do not.

Comment: Please also show your model's data() function too.

Comment: Well, you modify an array `Data[][]` in you `setData()` function, but your `data()` function doesn't even use the same array to display its content. Why do you expect that your view will show something else - it is simply static.

Comment: such a silly mistake. I misunderstood that data function is used only for first time display remain handled by set data and datachange signal. thanks!

Comment: You don't need to connect dataChanged to any slots of view directly!!!

Comment: @DmitrySazonov yeah you are right I just tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some notes here that can be taken.

- You should emit the `dataChanged()` signal once the data is updated properly.
- You do not seem to use the 2D array variable called "Data" in your `data()` function that you set up properly in the `setData()` method. You need to use the (same) variable at both places.
- You should not connect the `dataChanged()` signal to any slot. It will work out automatically for you.